# illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I created one documentry in Illustrator (1000 px x 1000 px). then I draw my illustration  in 200 px x 200 px cube. so that the total 25 cubes  cover the 1000px x 1000 px area. but when I copy paste that 200px x200 px cube in photoshop it becomes so bigger! my photoshop document on which I pasted is also 1000px x 1000 px.

I want the size to be same when I copy paste that. :'( Any way I can do it?

I tried properties panel in photoshop to reduce the size in 200 px x 200 px. but that does not keep the design proportion as it was in illustrator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: illustrator assumes a pixel is 72th of an inch if your ohotoshop isnt set that way then they wont match. if you really want them to match you design at same physical size.

Comment: Thank you so much. I badly needed it. to know  :'(

Comment: How much bigger is it when imported into Photoshop? If it's just a little bit, it could be that you need to align your illustrator border to the inside of your box. My illustrator aligns the stroke by default to the "middle", but you have "inside" or "outside" options. Depending how thick the stroke is, it could slightly interfere with exact measurements.
https://praestocreative.com/images/stroke-graphic.png